# Frame in canvas will not expand to fit canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am not sure why this will not work. I must be missing something because I can make a single frame expand to fit the canvas but I cannot make a frame inside a frame expand to fit the canvas.

I have been fighting with this for hours and I feel like its something obvious.

I am expecting the label inside of the `NoteFrame` to expand to fill the frame and that NoteFrame expand to fill the canvas.

Here is the minimum code to reproduce the behavior code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class NoteFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.config(background='white')
        for i in range(20):
            tk.Label(self, text='test').grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='nsew')


class GCMain(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.main_canvas = tk.Canvas(self, background="bisque")
        self.main_canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.main_canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_n_canvas = tk.Frame(self.main_canvas)
        self.frame_n_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') # tried with and without this
        self.frame_n_canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.main_canvas.config(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox("all"), highlightthickness=0)
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical')
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')
        scrollbar.config(command=self.main_canvas.yview)
        self.main_canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.main_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.main_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame_n_canvas, anchor='nw')
        self.main_canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.update_scrollregion)

        nf = NoteFrame(self.frame_n_canvas)
        nf.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') # tried with and without this

    def on_resize(self, event):
        w, h = event.width, event.height
        self.main_canvas.configure(width=w, height=h)
        self.frame_n_canvas(width=w, height=h) # tried with and without this

    def update_scrollregion(self, event):
        self.main_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.main_canvas.bbox("all"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GCMain().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Comment**: Dynamic solution

1. Allow your `Label` to be `sticky='ew'` use `.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

   ```
   class NoteFrame(tk.Frame):
       def __init__(self, container):
           super().__init__(container)
           self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
   ```
2. You need the item `iid` of the `Canvas(..., window=` object.
   **No** parameter `width=200, height=200` are needed!

   ```
   self.main_canvas.fram_n_canvas_iid =\
           self.main_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame_n_canvas, anchor='nw')
   ```
3. Bind to `"<Configure>` as known.

   ```
   self.main_canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.canvas_configure)
   ```
4. Resize `.frame_n_canvas` **width** in sync with `.main_canvas` **width**.

   ```
   def canvas_configure(self, event):
       canvas = event.widget
       canvas.itemconfigure(canvas.fram_n_canvas_iid, width=canvas.winfo_width())
   ```

[image]
[image]

---

> **Question**: Frame in canvas will not expand to fit canvas

A widget, here your Frame `self.frame_n_canvas`, looses the ability to `expand`, if placed with `.create_window(...` in a `Canvas`.

This, `.grid(...`, is useless, as you later place the same `Frame` with `.create_window(...`:

```
self.frame_n_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew') # tried with and without this
...
self.main_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame_n_canvas, anchor='nw')
```

To give your `NoteFrame` place to expand, use parameter `width=200, height=200`.

```
self.main_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame_n_canvas, anchor='nw',
                               width=200, height=200)
```

To allow your `Label` to be `sticky='ew'`, you have to do `.grid_columnconfigure(...`:

```
class NoteFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Hey stovfl. Thanks for the post but I am still unable to resize the frame with the canvas. Adding a width and height to the create_window option does expand the frame but for some reason I am unable to resize the width/height later. I have tried to define width/height with the frame directly and also with canvas.itemconfig. Any idea why the frame does not expand to fill the canvas completely?

Comment: @Mike-SMT: Updated my Answer with a image showing my result on only adding `.create_window(..., width=200, height=200)` and `self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to your questions code. Please confirm if this is what you want or explain why not.

Comment: I need the frame to expand all the way to the right as well. Filling the entire canvas.

Comment: I had added more to my question as it is very hard to explain the issue in a MCVE. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: *"Filling the entire canvas"*: My fixed values `=200` are only for example to show `Label sticky='ew'` is working.  I assume you want a dynamic solution, therefore you have to get the size of `.main_canvas` and resize the **`item`** `.main_canvas.create_window(...` accordingly.

Comment: I have tried. It does not work. The frame never resize. I am in a meeting right now so I will play with it some more later but I have spent the better part of 6 hours trying to get this to work. I know its something simple I am missing.

Comment: Hum I could not get it to work in my MCVE to include proper scrollbar movement however it worked to fix my main code. Thank you very much.